# Sqlalchemy before_execute event - how to pass some external variable, say app user id?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to obtain an application variable (app user id) in `before_execute(conn, clauseelement, multiparam, param)` method. The app user id is stored in python http request object which I do not have any access to in the db event.

Is there any way to associate a piece of sqlalchemy external data somewhere to fetch it in `before_execute` event later?

Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here with a possible solution :)

1. From http request copied the piece of data to session object
2. Since the session binding was at engine level, copied the data from session to connection object in `SessionEvent.after_begin(session, transaction, connection)`. [Had it been Connection level binding, we could have directly set the objects from session object to connection object.]

Now the data is available in connection object and in `before_execute()` too.